# Binding issue linked to DispatcherTimer

Tags: xaml, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

I'm building a Universal Windows Application which will allow users to track the time spent on a specific task.

On my Mainpage I'm binding an ObservableCollection, containing the time registrations. When a task is running I want to update the time spent every second.

I'm using a DispatcherTimer (whichs runs fine) to update the time spent for all active timers. I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and I'm firing the PropertyChanged event in the setter of the property which is binded to my XAML.

**The Problem**

I'm expecting my UI to update every second but it only updates once - each run - and does so at very irregular timestamps. I think I'm doing something wrong with my binding.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

**MainPage_loaded**

```
    private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimerRepository repository = new TimerRepository();
        this.Timers = await repository.GetTimersAsync();

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
        _timer.Start();
    }
```

**Dispatcher Timer, 1 second tick handling:**

```
    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (this.Timers != null)
        {
            foreach (var timer in this.Timers.Where(m => m.IsRunning))
            {
                timer.Tick();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Custom Timer Model**

```
public class SprintTimer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private DateTime? _timerStarted;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private TimeSpan _registedTime;
    public TimeSpan RegisteredTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _registedTime;
        }
        set
        {
            _registedTime = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RegisteredTime"));
        }
    }

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get
        {
            return this._timerStarted.HasValue;
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (!this._timerStarted.HasValue)
        {
            _timerStarted = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    public void Tick()
    {
        if (this.IsRunning)
        {
            this.RegisteredTime = DateTime.Now - _timerStarted.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ScrollViewer BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20 20 20 0">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind Timers, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:SprintTimer">
                        <Grid BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind RegisteredTime}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="22" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
                            <Button Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Name="btnStartTimer" Click="btnStartTimer_Click">
                                <SymbolIcon x:Name="icon" Symbol="Play"></SymbolIcon>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

**UI**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default mode of x:Bind is OneTime, you need to add `Mode=OneWay` to all the binding expressions.

Comment: Can't believe I missed this. Thank you so much!